# Браузер на андроид. WebView не все открывает

Tags: java, android, webview, браузер

Извиняюсь за не понятный заголовок, но я просто незнаю в чем именно проблема.
Написал браузер на андроид, страницы открывает, вроде все отлично, но на одном сайте при открытии "кассы" (скриншот внизу) открывается пустое окно. Если войти обычным браузером с телефона, то все открывается нормально.

Так открывается в обычном браузере.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моем браузере касса не открывается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я немогу понять, что именно не так с браузером

Исходник

Activity.java

```
private WebView webView ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
// указываем страницу загрузки
webView.loadUrl("http://mds.cashpla.net/go/cp-233136184");

// включаем поддержку JavaScript
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


// для того чтобы небыло перехода на другой браузер
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
});


webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
    }
});

//webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

// скрыть тулбар
getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте разрешить яваСкрипт

Comment: Я вроде добавил разрещешие webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);